# i will display editable alertview when aplication is going to background process to active process in ios

Tags: ios, uialertview

hii friends i will create password type alertview.when application is come to background to active mode that time password alertview display.than after i will minimize second time app than after i will open the app than time two times display alertview in to the app.like last time background alertview and current alertview.but i want only one alertview anytime.
here is my code
Appdelegate.m

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {


    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Password?"
                                                      message:nil
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];

    [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
    UITextField *textField = [message textFieldAtIndex:0];
    assert(textField);
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [message show];

       // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {




}

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *password = [defaults objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    if( [inputText isEqualToString:password] )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

please solve my problem friends.thanks for advance

Comment: UIAlertView is deprectaed. Use UIAlertController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple add this line below Appdelegate.m file where you create the alertview.

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification){
        [message dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the app second time, loop through all subviews and when you find a match for:

```
    isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]
```

remove that view from the superview, and present the alert again.

Comment: pls explain detail bro

Comment: when you want to remove previous alertview, scan through all subviews present at that moment, and when u find a subview which is kindofclass uialertclass, then remove that subview from superview.